# video retrieval techniques

Tags: java, matlab, opencv, information-retrieval

Hi What all techniques and algorithms used for video retrieval.
which platform shall i choose opencv or matlab?
My input is text or image query and output should be related videos containing text or image, suggest me exact topic for this project tat is which technique suits for this.
please give me references of this and also refer simple video retrieval source code.Help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For video retrieval you have to start with indexing the videos you have in your dataset. This is done frame by frame based to get feature descriptors (not usually there is a published paper to select dynamical feature rich frames only).

Feature descriptors for image(a video frame) can be computed using Opencv or matlab. There is a library both in c++ and matlab implementation like SURF, SIFT,MSER..

After that you have to build a so called "database" for the extracted features from the video , one option to do this is using "bag of words" model. This is also implemented in opencv and there are matlab libraries like check [vlfeat.org](http://vlfeat.org). In this case query can be done using image.

For text search in video ,may be you can try to extract the semantic content of the video and match it with the text context. Or while extracting features from the video frames try also to extract the texts than do some kind of database using "bag of words" model.

Comment: any source code references above SIFT and bag of words pls.

Comment: for bag of words check http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/08/25/a-simple-object-classifier-with-bag-of-words-using-opencv-2-3-w-code/  for SIFT refer to Opencv documentation http://docs.opencv.org, also SIFT is not free